# Can't right-click Taskbar Icons on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, context-menu, right-click

I restarted my PC many times, I also have restarted the Windows Explorer task but it doesn't work. I cannot right-click icons on Taskbar, I can't even click on the Start menu.
EDIT: I don't know if this helps or not, but some of Windows 10 programs are missing now, such as "Groove Music" and "Store".

Comment: Try Ctrl+right click and Shift+right click, then normal right click. Do they help at all?

Comment: @MC10 It does not work.

Comment: Is there anything else you can't right click? Maybe there was a program in your previous version of Windows that added something to the context menu and now it isn't behaving corrrectly.

Comment: @MC10 I just can't right click the icons on taskbar, also, I cannot open Start menu and Search input.

Comment: What about restarting the `Tile Data Model Server` service mentioned here: http://superuser.com/questions/947789/cant-right-click-on-windows-10-taskbar-icons, does it help at all? Is this a laptop with a touchpad?

Comment: @MC10 Same, I still can't left-click on Start menu and right-click on Taskbar icons.

Comment: Does right click from the keyboard work? (try to left click on an icon to select it than press the button the right on your keyboard between the `Win key` and right `Ctrl`) `Win key + R` work? Also Check if `Ctrl + Shift + Esc` brings up the task manager.

Comment: No, it just doesn't.

Comment: Horrible decision to "duplicate it" into that URL. That URL does NOT have a solution, at best it has a very short-lived workaround that does not even address a problem at all.

Comment: Shift/rt. click works for me. Thanks @MC10

Comment: The answers at the linked post are not answers.  The answers here are at least potentially useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This fixed it for me](http://www.bidnessetc.com/49429-microsoft-windows-10-start-menu-cortana-taskbar-not-working-heres-fix/):

> **Step 1:** Right-click the Start button and select Command Prompt (Admin)
>   from the context menu.
>
> **Step 2:** Type **Powershell** in Command Prompt and press Enter.
>
> **Step 3:** Paste the following text in the Powershell window and press
>   Enter.
>
> **Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}**
>
> Wait for the command to run and ignore the red error prompts if they
>   arise. The Start Menu should be operational now.
>
> Search and Cortana malfunctioning can be attributed to a corrupted
>   search index database in most cases. To fix it, all you need to do is
>   delete and rebuilt the Search Index. To do this, head to the Control
>   Panel. Locate the Indexing Options utility and launch it. The utility
>   will display a list of all the locations and applications currently
>   being indexed. Check to see if all the drives and folders are being
>   indexed. To add an item, press Modify and you’ll be presented with a
>   list of all locations on the PC; tick ones you require and clock OK.
>
> **How To Rebuild Windows Search Index On Windows 10**
>
> Even if all the correct locations are being indexed, a malfunctioning
>   Search Index can render the Search function useless. Before we delve
>   into the method, keep in mind that the index rebuilding process may
>   take a while and will affect system performance as well until
>   completion. To rebuild the Index, open Indexing Options. Click on
>   Advanced Options and press the Rebuild button in the Troubleshooting
>   section. Click OK on the confirmation prompt and the process will
>   start.

[image]

Comment: These steps are not working for me.

Comment: did you get any errors and what are your exact symptoms as there are multiple issues i see in this thread...for example i have no issues with cortana, just the start & taskbar would not work on mine. this fixed both

Comment: After a lot of searching I found that Windows cannot deal with a user's directory being a junction (unbelievable). After moving the main user and appdata directories to a local one and running the commands above now the store works, start menu works, right-click on taskbar icons works. Search still does not work, though.

Comment: I can confirm that this DID fix it for me on Windows 10. When I tried right clicking on any icon in the taskbar, nothing happened. I had to use windows explorer to navigate to C:\Windows\System32, find cmd, and right click to run that as administrator. Then I typed powershell, and ran the script. Now everything works!

Comment: The other answers from the duplicate question do not work for me. This is the only thing that did.

Comment: They should remove the "duplicate" flag from this and turn this into a proper solution thread. The other one does not even have a solution, only a workaround that does not even work for 1 minute after it is applied. This actually does solve problems.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it for me, with Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063. Although, it will be interesting to know, why this is happening, and doesn't even gets solved after full system restart.

Comment: I have this problem and I see "waiting to receive indexing status" in the Indexing Options window. This is Windows 1809.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks a ton!