# left Mouse buttons don't work - System Tray

Tags: windows-10, mouse, notification-area

I have a weird problem (running Windows 10).

My left mouse button doesn't work on icons in the system tray and my right mouse button doesn't work in the toolbar.  So for instance if I left click on the wireless internet control in the system tray nothing happens. Mousing over it gives me the tips and right clicking works, but the left click doesn't.  A similar (but of course opposite) problem happens down in the toolbar.  A left mouse click on Chrome starts it up but right mouse click doesn't show the incognito etc options.

I have the same issue if I use the laptop mouse or a wireless mouse.

Comment: Is there anything logged in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Right Click on Windows 10 Taskbar Icons](http://superuser.com/questions/947789/cant-right-click-on-windows-10-taskbar-icons)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to finally fix the issue from the following (run in PowerShell)

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` [(source)](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-fix-start-menu-in-windows-10-3623893/)

Comment: Very nice answer, it's good you provided a source too.

Comment: This worked for me. I got a few errors during the powershell command, but it solved the problem.