# Windows 10 taskbar not working with right click

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 and I can't left click the windows button, use the windows key, or even right click an application on there. How can I fix this? Resetting has not worked, nor the task manager reset, nor the code typed in cmd. This occured after a restore.

Comment: This is a known issue with windows 10. The easiest route is to restart and see if that changes it. If the behavior is the same after a restart, then there are some features that need to be reinstalled. Try the restart first and if it doesn't fix it, we can go down the other road.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly leave out important details of what they have tried and what research they have done. After you try what Narzard suggested, please [edit] your question to include more details. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Restarting doesnt help.

Comment: This probably won't apply to you but then again it may so it's worth a shot: there is a group policy setting that prevents users from right-clicking on their taskbar. Our orginization has that enabled, and we cannot right-click on our Start Menu, Taskbar, or Desktop, or in Windows Explorer. Is that by chance enabled on your system?

Comment: Rather than my adding a new answer here, consider a solution I found today: https://superuser.com/a/1663490/154827

Answer (score 1):

You can also try resetting explorer.

Press Control + Shift + Escape.

Choose the "Processes" tab.

Find "Windows Explorer" Right click and choose restart.

[image: Task mgr]

[More information found in this thread.](https://superuser.com/questions/947789/cant-right-click-on-windows-10-taskbar-icons?rq=1)