# No right-click menu for VS 2015 in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-v1511

In Windows 10, I can't get a context menu when right-clicking the Visual Studio 2015 icon in the start menu nor on the taskbar.

The icon is visible, but when I right-click on it, I get no context menu.  I am trying to unpin the icon from the menus so that I can try to re-pin it to get jump lists working, but in order to remove the pinned icon from the taskbar, I have to go directly to the AppData folder and navigate to my taskbar folder and delete the icon from that location.

All other icons offer a context menu when I right-click, and I can pin/unpin other applications normally.  Visual Studio 2015 seems to be acting up.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro x64 Version 1511, OS Build 10586.318.

Comment: Is what you are looking for found by pressing Shift and then right clicking the icon?

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me. I noticed restarting my computer fixed the issue, but that isn't a good solution.

I then found this:
[Can't Right Click on Windows 10 Taskbar Icons](https://superuser.com/questions/947789/cant-right-click-on-windows-10-taskbar-icons)

"Press control shift escape then locate windows explorer in the windows processes. Right click windows explorer then click restart."

I now have my context menus back! Hope this helps.

Comment: You should flag this question as a duplicate of that question, if there is an answer to that question, that solves the author's problem instead of submitting your own answer.

Comment: Restarting windows explorer nor restarting my PC fixes this issue.  It is not the same as the link you provided.  My problem is specific to Visual Studio 2015